# Why are win32/Standard library function parameters almost always passed as pointers and not references?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, pointers, reference

From my personal cpp experience, I learned to pass objects to a function by pointer if such parameter can be NULL and by reference if the parameter should never be NULL/should be instantiated before being passed.
I was wondering then, why when writing functions such as

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateFile(
  _In_      LPCTSTR lpFileName,
...
);
```

or

```
explicit basic_iostream(basic_streambuf<Elem, Tr> *_Strbuf);
```

Microsoft chose to take such parameters as pointers rather than references, especially since the function just errors when passed a NULL value...

So why is it that every time a string (or other type) is passed as a parameter, it is passed as a pointer (and not a reference)?

I am asking this because I have yet to see any instances where you pass in strings by reference rather than by pointer, and I feel like I am missing some verifiable reason, which I could reflect in my code, as to why it is done this way.

Comment: What would passing a `char *` string by reference look like?

Comment: This is *not* the standard library this is Win32 API.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Can't you pass a std::wstring as a reference?
void myfunc(std::wstring &myStr);

Comment: WinAPI is not C++. There are no references in C.

Comment: It's a 20 year old C api !

Comment: This is not standard library, this is Windows API. It can be called not only from C++.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus make it an answer

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Quite a bit of it came from 16-bit Windows, so it's even older than that.

Comment: I don't think I have gotten the answer I am looking for yet.
I now understand why this is done in Win32, but still don't understand why it would be done in the standard library.

For example, see the following page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404762(v=vs.120).aspx

Here, the _Strbuf parameter "requires an existing basic_streambuf object", but such parameter is passed as a pointer.

Comment: It's not Microsoft that chose to make it take a pointer. It's the ISO/IEC-standard that *mandates* this constructor signature (pre-C++11). You're also missing another scenario where passing a pointer vs. a reference is used: Passing ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the Win32 API, not the standard library.

Win32 uses pointers instead of references, because it's intended to be language independent. To that end, it uses C (or something similar) as the "least common denominator" -- and C doesn't have a reference type, so the API doesn't use it either.

The C++ standard library does use references quite a bit (e.g., almost everything that works with `iostream`s passes them by reference).

Comment: "I don't think I have gotten the answer I am looking for yet. I now understand why this is done in Win32, but still don't understand why it would be done in the standard library. For example, see the following page: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404762(v=vs.120).aspx Here, the _Strbuf parameter "requires an existing basic_streambuf object", but such parameter is passed as a pointer."

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera, Do you really want to venture into streambufs?

Comment: @chris I really just want to know what standards the people who wrote this are following, because clearly they are following a different philosophy than mine, and I could be wrong.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera, You'll find that most things in the standard library use references instead of pointers. There are also iterators, which are like pointers, but they serve a different purpose. I can't speak too much for streambufs, due to my lack of knowledge in the area, but I believe they're typically held and operated on as pointers.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: If you were designing that particular function today, you'd probably want to use a `std::unique_ptr` -- you're basically transferring ownership of the buffer object to the stream object. iostreams predate both `unique_ptr` and `auto_ptr` though. Since you are transferring ownership, however, it's usually dynamically allocated, so the pointer ends up working out all right anyway.

Comment: Firstly, the streambuffer can be null. Secondly, Jerry is unfortunately wrong, the streambuffer should not be deallocated with the stream, as multiple streams can share a streambuffer. If you really wanted to replace this with a smart pointer, I would suggest using a shared_ptr instead. However, the IOStreams library (which was later incorporated into the C++ standard) predates such smart pointers. Maybe it is even older than templates, I know that the original IOStreams were not parametrized on the character type.